# Php-fpm doesn't receive "client prematurely closed connection" from NGINX

Tags: php, nginx

I have nginx version: 1.12.0 and the following configuration:

```
http {
 server {

  listen      443;
  server_name SERVER_NAME_OR_IP;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  debug;

  ssl                  on;
  ssl_certificate      /path/to/cert.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/cert.key;
  ssl_protocols        TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

  location ~* /test/abcd/ {

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7000;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $http_host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_address;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  }
 }
 server {
   listen       127.0.0.1:7000;
   server_name  SERVER_NAME_OR_IP;

   location / {

     location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
       fastcgi_param   PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 3072M \n post_max_size=3072M";
       include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
     }
   }
}
```

If the client closes connection during uploading a file, I see in /var/log/error.log : "epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too while sending request to upstream" and "client prematurely closed connection" . My problem is that php-fpm doesn't receive that error when client closes connection, so I can't catch this error in my code. Do you know what might be the problem?

Thank You!

Comment: So what should happen according to you?

Comment: I should be able to catch this error in my php code(http://php.net/manual/ro/features.connection-handling.php) and I think that the "client prematurely closed connection info" should appear in  /var/log/php-fpm.log .

Comment: AFAIU your script wont be even called till the upload is complete, so you can't handle such a thing in code.